# Nexus 6P android beta 7.1.2 pop up error message: Alternating TimerReceiver() onReceive() - Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, nexus-6p

I enrolled for Android beta updates and I recently upgraded my nexus 6P to version 7.1.2 . since 2 days a message pop up in my phone which i showed in picture, it cover my keyboard but i can operate keyboard even when pop up presents.
Error message says it is attempting to invoke virtual method but i am not sure whether it is about particular application or OS level.

[Alternating TimerReceiver onReceive() -attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(java.lang.string)'on a null object reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcmwg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the app light manager installed? It should be that app generating this pop up. It's not a problem but it's annoying. It should be fixed, I have it too: Pixel XL, Nougat 7.1.1

Comment: Yes , you are correct. uninstalling light manager fixed my issue. Thank you